# prove that in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is an entire function such that $|f'(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z \in C$. Show that $f$ must be of the form $f(z) = a z^2 + b$ where $a$, $b$ are complex constants such that $|a| \leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please try to use LaTex to typeset your question.

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is entire then so is $f'$

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Let $g=f'$. Prove that $g(0)=0$ and that $g(z)/z$ is entire. Then use Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, for any positive integer $k$, show that $f^{(1+k)}(0) = 0$. This can be done using Cauchy’s Estimates on disks centered at the origin with arbitrarily large radii. Since $f$ is entire, it has a power series centered at the origin and the coefficients for the square term and on will vanish leaving either a constant or linear polynomial. The details are left to you.